# Binding singleton in SLB

Tags: c++, lua, singleton

I have singleton class and I would like to bind it for lua to use. I'm using SLB (Simple Lua Binder). I really have no idea how to do this. All my ideas just dont work. Anyone?

```
void Logger::export_class_to_lua(SLB::Manager *m) {
    SLB::Class< Logger, SLB::Instance::NoCopyNoDestroy >("Logger",m)
        .set("getInstance",&Logger::getInstance)
        .set("log",&Logger::log)
        .set("info",&Logger::info)
        .set("warning",&Logger::warning)
        .set("error",&Logger::error)
        .set("fatal",&Logger::fatal);
}
```

Comment: `.set("foo", std::bind(&Logger::foo, Logger::getInstance()))` Assuming `getInstance` returns a pointer. Take address if it returns by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code do:

```
void Logger::export_class_to_lua(SLB::Manager *m) {
    SLB::Class< Logger, SLB::Instance::NoCopyNoDestroy >("Logger",m)
        //.set("getInstance",&Logger::getInstance) // OMIT THIS
        .set("log",&Logger::log)
        .set("info",&Logger::info)
        .set("warning",&Logger::warning)
        .set("error",&Logger::error)
        .set("fatal",&Logger::fatal);

    // Next we set global variable within LUA to access the Singleton
    SLB::setGlobal<Logger*>(&(*lua_State), getInstance(), "logger");
}
```

lua_State will be a pointer to whatever lua_State you created.
"logger" is the name of the object/class/variable you use within LUA to access the Singleton.

So for example; inside of LUA you would do:

```
logger:log("Logging some information.")
logger:error("An error has occured.")
```

Assuming your log and error functions take const char* or something.